# Jquery sum form inputs in multiple tables

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have a PHP page that populates HTML tables from MySQL.  It outputs two seperate tables with the IDs 'headTable' and 'visits'.  I am trying to sum the values from the 'visit' table and output the sum to the corresponding 'headTable'.  There is also a checkbox that populates the input field and I am also having trouble getting the correct sum when checking all of the check boxes.  The sum is correct if I manually type in the values.  Thanks in advance.
[Here is an Example on Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nspinelli/gXdwb/116/)

```
<table id="headTable">
    <tr>
        <th>First Table</th>
        <th><span id="appliedTotal"></span></th>
    </tr>
</table>

<table id="visits">
    <tr>
        <td>Jane</td>
        <td>18.45</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
        <td><input class="amount" type="text" size="20" value=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Peter</td>
        <td>100</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
        <td><input class="amount" type="text" size="20" value=""></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<table id="headTable">
    <tr>
        <th>Second Table</th>
        <th><span id="appliedTotal"></span></th>
    </tr>
</table>

<table id="visits">
    <tr>
        <td>Ronald</td>
        <td>100</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
        <td><input class="amount" type="text" size="20" value=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>100</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
        <td><input class="amount" type="text" size="20" value=""></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and for my Jquery

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(function() {

        $('table input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {
            var input = $(this).closest('td').next('td').find('input');

            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                var amount = $(this).closest('td').prev('td').text();
                var sum = 0;

                $.each($('table#visits'), function() {
                    $('.amount').each(function() {
                        sum += Number($(this).val());
                        $('#appliedTotal').html('$'+sum.toFixed(2));
                    });
                });

                input.val(amount);

            } else {
                input.val('0.00');
                var sum = 0;

                $('.amount').each(function() {
                    sum += Number($(this).val());
                    $('#appliedTotal').html('$'+sum.toFixed(2));
                });

            }
        });
    });

    $.each($('table#visits'), function() {
        $(".amount").keyup(function() {
            var sum = 0;

            $('.amount').each(function() {
                sum += Number($(this).val());
                $('#appliedTotal').html(sum);
            });
        });
    });

});
</script>
```

---

This is what I was looking to do.

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/nspinelli/gXdwb/116/)

Comment: You haven't asked a specific question.  But if you need to sum some inputs in jquery, then what's stopping you from giving all the inputs in question a common class and grabbing them by class?

Comment: My question is I want to sum the values by table and output the sum into the corresponding 'headTable'.  This code sums all of the values from both tables and it isin't even the right sum.  I am drawing a blank here...

Answer (score 0):

is it about how to make numbers from dollars? I prefer opposite, but for you case add substring(1) to .val() before passing it to Number()

and a 
     sum = '$' + sum
before assign to the appliedTotal of course

Comment: No.  I am trying to sum the values from each individual table with the id 'visits' and output the sum to the corresponding table with the id 'headTable'.

Answer (score 0):

you can't have two tables or any other tags with the same 'id' at one page.

Comment: select tables with data by class instead. or put them all inside separate div and use that notion as the selector.